# Two python lists to nested dictionaries repeating pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to transform two lists of equal length which contain key:value pairs into nested dictionaries.

List look like

```
list1 = ['first_name', 'surname', 'BoB', 'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2',  'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2']

list2 = ['John', 'Smith', 10/10/1980, 'Q1', 'some text', 'other text', 'Q2', 'different text', 'more text']
```

Current code

```py
for key in name_list:
    for value in values_list:
        data[key] = value
        values_list.remove(value)
        break
```

Current output is a single dictionary

```py
{'first_name':'John', 'surname':'Smith', 'BoB':10/10/1980, 'Question_no':'Q1', 'comment1':'some text', 'comment2':'other text',  'Question_no':'Q2', 'comment1':'different text', 'comment2':'more text'}
```

The output I am look for is to have the repeating parts in their own structure.

```py
{
'details' : {'first_name':'John', 'surname':'Smith', 'BoB':10/10/1980}, 
001 : {'Question_no':'Q1', 'comment1':'some text', 'comment2':'other text'}, 
002 : {'Question_no':'Q2', 'comment1':'different text', 'comment2':'more text'}
}
```

There will be a differing number of Questions in each.

Many thanks

Comment: you forgot the quotes around `10/10/1980` and `001` is not a valid number format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things that should change in the given approach

1. You don't need to use nested for loops for building the dictionary. Instead, you need to iterate over the lists at the same time because the elements at position `i` correspond to each other.
2. Building the dictionary only through `data[key] = value` will not create a nested one. You need to specify it like `data[outer_key][inner_key] = value` or `data[outer_key] = {'first_name': 'John'}`.

Please see the code below to understand how you can address these.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)

def get_outer_key(previous_outer_key):
    if previous_outer_key == 'details':
        return 1
    return previous_outer_key + 1

outer_key = 'details'

name_list = ['first_name', 'surname', 'BoB', 'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2',  'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2']

values_list = ['John', 'Smith', '10/10/1980', 'Q1', 'some text', 'other text', 'Q2', 'different text', 'more text']

for i, key in enumerate(name_list):
    if key == 'Question_no':
        outer_key = get_outer_key(outer_key)
    value = values_list[i]
    data[outer_key][key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the task as before the occurence of the `'Question_no'` term and after.

- find the position of the threshold term, `n = list1.index('Question_no')`
- The before part: just cast to dict the (cartesian) product of the two sliced lists, `zip(list1[:n], list2[:n])`
- the after part: *group first* and then apply the same approach as in part1
- merge the the results together: composition of dict: `dict(d1 , **d2)`

```
list1 = ['first_name', 'surname', 'BoB', 'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2',  'Question_no', 'comment1', 'comment2']

list2 = ['John', 'Smith', '10/10/1980', 'Q1', 'some text', 'other text', 'Q2', 'different text', 'more text']

out_tail_lst = []
n = list1.index('Question_no')
for v1, v2  in zip(list1[n:], list2[n:]):
    if v1 !='Question_no':
        out_tail_lst[-1].append((v1, v2))
    else:
        out_tail_lst.append([(v1, v2)])


out_tail_dct = {f'00{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(map(dict, out_tail_lst), 1)}

out = {'details': dict(zip(list1[:n], list2[:n]))} | out_tail_dct

print(out)
```

Remark: the keys `001` can be done with f-string

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The problem with this solution is that if the order of the list changes it breaks. e.g. if ```'comment1',``` was before ```'Question_no',``` in the list order.

Comment: @Cam Hi! Mmm... not sure to understand. You mentioned **key-value pairs**, so for me, you cannot change the position of single term of a list but both at the same time: `'comment1'` is tight together with `'some text'`

Comment: Yes sorry, they are key pairs. ```'comment1'``` and ```'some text'``` are a pair but if that pair was before ```'Question_no'``` and ```'Q1'```. It would break your solution. Because ```'comment1'``` and ```'some text'``` would endup in the wrong dict.

Comment: @Cam Hi! I forgot the `details`-key, sorry for that! Now I edited with the correct `out`. Thanks for that!